# How could I hide a field with a button in Odoo

Tags: odoo

Currently, I had a view form and there is some field that need to be hide or unhide by click a button.
I tried to use State, Boolean field but unable to achieve the result.
My question is could I do it on Odoo and how?

I used State and Boolean field and set by condition on field, however the result was not good.
When a user clicks a button, hidden field will appear back

Comment: Can you include the code of the fields in the xml and the code of the action that gets called clicking the button?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it.

Button action in odoo triggers write method before being executed.
You should be aware of this before implementing your logic and your domains in order to show/hide fields in XML Views.

Your need is to use `invisible` attribute applied to a domain inside your field.
`invisible` is normally static, but can be elasticised inside `attrs` attribute.

Another important thing is, field-based domains requires the field to be present in view in order to access it. A good practice is to make these fields invisible and put them on top of your view.

In your model:

```
show_fields = fields.Boolean(default=False)
field_to_show = fields.Char()

def show_fields_action(self):
  for record in self: record.show_fields = True
```

In your view:

```
<field name="show_fields" invisible="1" />
<field name="field_to_show" attrs="{'domain': [('show_fields','=',True])}" />

<button name="show_fields_action" type="object" string="Show Fields" />
```

If your question UI/UX related, consider using `notebooks` instead.